# How to change the font of the code chunks in a PDF knitted from R studio?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I tend to comment my code using ligatures of lines. See example:

[image]

The font I'm using is Cascadia Code (Pre-Installed in RStudio Server)

When RStudio knits my document into a PDF, it changes the font, hence the ligatures are not supported:

[image]

I would like to use Cascadia Code for my Knitted PDFs so the ligatures look the same there, I was wondering if there's a way to do that. All the documentation I found was only about changing the font of the text (not the code chunks)

Thank you!